# Does a beam splitter alter the total probability for measuring a photon, if both paths lead to a measurement device?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

First assume there is no beam splitter. An apparatus emits (unmeasured electromagnetic waves corresponding to) single photons. It is directed towards a measurement device, suited to measure practically all the photons heading its way.

Then, instead, assume there is a beam splitter, and two measurement devices, similar to the original one. If we can assume that there is no loss of possible detections due to impurities or other practical issues, would the probability for measuring a photon be the same as if there was no beam splitter and only one measurement device?

I was wondering about the Elitzur-Vaidman Bomb Experiment.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhIf3Q_m0FQ&t=400s
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elitzur%E2%80%93Vaidman_bomb_tester
An apparatus emits single photons. Then there is a beam splitter, so that the photon has two possible paths, say, the upper and the lower. Then there are two mirrors, such that the paths meet again, in a second beam splitter. Beyond this second beam splitter, there are two measurement devices, A and B. The set up is such that B doesn't measure any photons due to destructive interferens. All the photons are measured by A (due to positive interferens). Then a "bomb" - actually a measurement device - is placed at the lower path. It can be active or not. If active, it has no more than 50% chance of measuring a photon due to the first beam splitter. But if it does not measure anything - if the "bomb" does not go off - the situation is still changed. Then B as well as A has a 25 % chance of measuring a photon. One could say that it is known that the photon followed the upper path (since the "bomb" did not go off). But is this necessarily true?

I was wondering if the "bomb" (the measurement device placed somewhere at the lower path) simply disturbs the interference pattern. If for instance the destructive interference pattern that prevented B from measuring any photons, is no longer present, then B could measure some photons without it being required that the photon followed the upper path and not the lower path (in some clear sense as if in a classical physics situation).

Then, say a measurement device is well suited for its task, and should be able to measure practically all single photons from the emitting apparatus. Because of the beam splitter in between, it still only measures 50% of the emitted photons. What then about the two final detectors in the set up, A and B? To rephrase my probably very silly question, I remove the "bomb" from the experiment set up. Is it like the A and B detectors "know" that one of them must detect the photon? Or is it like they can both miss the photon, like one could toss a coin twice and still don't get a tail?

Finally, if it is like the A and B detectors "know" that one of them must detect the photon - that the photon must take one of two paths and be measured somewhere when there is two possibilities and both are covered - does this mean that an attempt such as mine, to understand the bomb experiment simply in terms of interference being disturbed, is not doable?

I beg you pardon for not being able to express myself more clearly.

Comment: In general the problem with the experiment is that any detector absorbs the photon .. so it can not give any further information.  With a BS the paths are selected at random ... if both arms are optimal (path lengths = n x lambda). If one or both arms are length n x lambda + 0.5 no photons will be detected respectively .

Comment: Looking only at the first two paragraphs of your question: This experiment has been performed in a manner to answer that portion. See http://people.whitman.edu/~beckmk/QM/grangier/Thorn_ajp.pdf in which a pair of entangled photons is emitted; one goes directly to a detector, the other passes through your beam splitter on its way to the 2 detectors on that side. The coincidence statistics are presented, and you see how small the loss is. "Observing the quantum behavior of light in an undergraduate laboratory". I can't help you on the bomb tester, other than to say: Don't try this at home.

Comment: Is it for sure that any detector absorbs the photon - or rather: the 50% probability of a photon? i) The dud "bomb" doesn't seem to absorb the photon? ii) If the live "bomb", when not measuring, still must absorb the photon, then why do A or B also measure the photon afterwards? I was wondering if a detector, when it is live but does not detect the 50%-probability-of-a-photon, could just disturb it, say with its electromagnetic field, so that the destructive interference preventing B from measuring no longer holds.